# Odd macro and no operation variable usage?

Tags: c++, c, linux, function, macros

What does this two snippet code mean here?

```
#define HTTPH(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) char b[] =  "*" a ":";
```

```
void function(char *p) {
  (void)p;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one go, these are clearly different, and give them a title that describes them properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is string concatenation through macro. It is similar to:

```
#define STR3 STR1 STR2
```

With this the preprocessor will concatenate STR1 & STR2 and use it in place of STR3.
**[Example.](http://codepad.org/dvxw52K2)**

The second syntax:

```
void function(char *p)
{
  (void)p;
}
```

Means the pointer variable `p` is currently unused. Unused variables seldom result in compiler warnings, Such an construct is popularly used to get rid of the unused variable warning.

With `(void)p;` the pointer `p` is used in a statement(which in reality does nothing) But it satisfy's the compiler that the variable was used somewhere and hence it generates no warning.

Comment: I have seen that to avoid compiler warnings for unused variables.

Comment: @PatrickB.: Yes Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

The `"*" a ":"` is simple string concatination. Just like `"a" "b" "c"` is equivalent to `"abc"`.

The void function doesn't do anything, but it might a place holder for something else. You will need to show more context to get a proper answer.